# Can a super class return a subclass? For example for a Marry function?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, covariance

Say I have a method where I want to have with the return type the same as the class. e.g. `Cat:Marry(Cat y)` or `Dog:Marry(Dog y)` but I don't want a cat to marry a dog!

Is there a programming language that lets me express this and gives a compile time error if you try and marry a cat and a dog? e.g.

```
class Animal{
    void Marry(Animal X){
      Console.Write(this+" has married "+X);
   }
}
class Cat:Animal{}
class Dog:Animal{}
```

Thus I want `(new Cat()).Marry(new Cat())` to be allowed but not `(new Cat()).Marry(new Dog())`

In other words I want the argument type of Marry to match its class. Do any languages do this? (without having to write more than one Marry function?) I am envisaging something like this:

```
void Marry(caller X){
    Console.Write(this+" has married "+X);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Java using generics:

```
class Animal<T extends Animal> {
  void marry(T other) {
    ...
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal<Cat> { ... }
class Dog extends Animal<Dog> { ... }
```

Here's a chunk of code that I got working properly in Java 8, for those who would like a more specific answer:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Dog dog = new Dog();
        final Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.marry(cat);
        dog.marry(dog);
    }
}

class Animal <T extends Animal> {
    void marry(T other) {

    }
}

class Dog extends Animal<Dog> {

}

class Cat extends Animal<Cat> {

}
```

Comment: I believe it is the same idea in C#, just slightly different syntax: class Animal<T> where T : Animal

Comment: What about returning a type of T is that possible to? Would you have to cast Animal<T> to T?

Comment: Yes you can have a method return type T, not requiring a cast.

Comment: I tried this in sharp and it didn't work:  public class Animal<T>{
 T foo(){ return (T)this;}
}
public class Cat:Animal<Cat>{}

Comment: You'll need to post exactly what you tried for me to know what's going wrong. I made a version of this which compiled and behaved exactly as expected. I'll edit my post and paste the code in there so you can see.

Comment: For C# you need to do it as I explained in a previous comment, with the "where T : ..." part added. Otherwise it doesn't have the necessary constraint. I know it's hard to read in the comments, since we can't use the formatting. Maybe it would be better if someone posted a C# version as a separate answer. I'm not a C# expert, so I'll leave it to others who can better do this.

Comment: OK brilliant. Thanks! It works! :) public class Animal<T> where T:class{
 T foo(){ return this as T;}
}
public class Cat:Animal<Cat>{}

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve this in C++ using the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <typename Derived>
class Animal{
    void Marry(Derived X)
    {
       //code here  
    }
}

class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{
}

class Cat : Animal<Cat>
{
}
```